# c# How to add Application to Site with network directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-administration

I have a problem where adding Application to IIS Site with network physical path.

In code:

```
    using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
    ...
    ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
    var site = serverManager.Sites.Where(i => i.Name == "services").SingleOrDefault();
    site.Applications.Add("\\src\services\myservice", "myservice"); //exception
```

My application throws an exception "Invalid application path". I try to create a Virtual Directory, but I already catch this exception. Application pool and my program have a permissions to this network folder. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. .Applications.Add() method requires slash at beginning:

```
site.Applications.Add("\\src\services\myservice", "/myservice");
```